# How to show warning/error if used resource id belongs to another activity layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Is there a way to show some warning/error when Android resource id does not belong to layout inflated in Activity?

Following is simple example, but in more complex layouts it is much harder to track down such issues as they can only be found during run-time. I would like to be able to catch them at compile-time.

**MainActivity initialization**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // how to prevent erroneous usage of R.id.text2 at compile time
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you check `UnknownIdInLayout' of Lint? Read at http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Comment: @PankajKumar Lint check has passed without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any Lint checks or similar which can do what you require. I'd make a feature request because it looks like a useful feature.
For the time being I'd use prefixes in identifiers. E.g.:

```
findViewById(act_main_text1);
findViewById(act_main_text2);
root.findViewById(fragment_preferences_username);
```

And so on. It won't raise the error/warning during the build stage, but it'll make your life easier as you'll always know which activity/fragment/view this particular id belongs to.

Comment: [Feature request for Lint](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74703) has already been filed